# Overvolting brushed motors by 0.2V

Tags: voltage, batteries, motor, lipo, nimh

For RC models, I own several brushed motors which are intended to operate at 7,2V. According to my previous tests, they usually take 25 amps, 30 being the absolute maximum.

To divide by two the weight of a model, I plan to switch from a 7.2V NIMH battery to a 7.4V LIPO battery.

There will obviously be premature wear on the motor, but I would like to know if this wear will be very fast, rather slow, or maybe negligible ?

Thanks to anyone who can answer me.

Comment: Most likely will not have any appreciable effect on motor or ESC life. You may see a very tiny increase in maximum speed, at least when the battery is at full charge. You will certainly notice a drop in speed as the pack wears down, compared to NiMH.

Comment: 0.2V is nothing. 1.2V is treated as the nominal voltage for NiMH so that 7.2V NiMH pack is actually 6 cells, but NiMH is 1.55V peak so that 6-cell pack is actually  9.3V peak when fully charged. But NiMH voltages drop much faster as the cells are discharged than LiPo does.

Comment: The loaded Vbat is dependant on the ESR and thus mAh rating, SoC and age factor is more important than the no-load voltage.